# Is there a way to allow overflow html elements on the left side (or the negative x axis)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following unordered lists which I have arranged as circular elements on my webpage.

```
        <ul class="blocks" style="float:right">
              <li id = "block-1" class="block-1 orange"><div class="about">about me</div></li>
              <li id = "block-2" class="block-2 blue"><div class="random">random block</div></li>
              <li id = "block-3" class="block-3 pink"><div class="projects">projects</div></a></li>
        </ul>
```

As soon as I hover on one of the list element that element expands and the other two are supposed to move out the viewport screen. I am able to do it for the first list element as both the latter elements just overflow out in the right direction. But I am unable to do it for the other two elements since the list elements always prevent themselves from overflowing in the left direction. Is there any way to rectify this?

Comment: Are you using css as well? Could you update what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you provide javascript? This sounds like it can be accomplished with margin negative on click but don't understand what you've built so far.

Comment: @Coll you were right, it worked through a negative margin. thanks for your input!